# Should I edit someone else answer if it's wrong even if my answer was accepted?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette

I answered a question on SO and my answer was accepted. It received also a few up-votes. I then submitted an edit to another answer to the same question because it was not correct and the edit was accepted.

I did that because I think it could prevent from having people trying the wrong solution proposed and then coming back whining that it does not work adding unnecessary comments/replies.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes., you are...You should never edit someone elese answer for "correctness". At best you should have left a comment.

Comment: Ok, so suppose that after my comment the user updates the answer. Now it is correct as in the case of my edit. What's the difference then?

Comment: That's for person who answered to decide. If they're happy with their answer being wrong it's not for you to correct it. Comment, downvote and move on.

Comment: edit other people's posts only to fix grammar or formatting mistakes. Your edit should not change the content beyond that.

Comment: So should I roll back that edit? Or just learn the lesson for the future?

Comment: I agree with Servy - learn your lesson and move on.

Comment: @Paulie_D Is that an answer? Or a comment?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The edit was indeed inappropriate, and it merited rejection accordingly given that you were editing the content of the post, rather than the presentation of it, and clearly changing the author's intent.  That said, it was approved, not by reviewers, but by the post author, so while you shouldn't have made the edit (if you felt the post was wrong you should have commented and downvoted), you also shouldn't roll it back, given that the author of the post is the one who approved the change.

Comment: It was then rolled back by someone else. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38607679/revisions

Comment: @Marc.2377 You linked to the wrong revision history. Anyway, the rollback was rolled back again by the same user.

Comment: I did! here is the correct one: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38607385/revisions - and nice to see it was re-rolled.

Comment: @Marc.2377 should I call Rick? He know everything about Rollers